# How to calculate memory size of complex map variable

Tags: go

I am trying to calculate the size of a variable (EntryMap) in memory.

```
type Entry interface {
    A() string
    B() string
    C() time.Time
    D() int64
}

type Entries []Entry
type EntryMap map[string]Entries
```

What I got so far is this:

```
hm = make(EntryMap)
SizeInMem = 8 //Length of Empty HMap

for key, value := range hm {
    A = 8 // For each Key Value Assignment
    B = len(Key) + 1 // Size of key string var
    C = len(Entries) * unsafe.Sizeof(Entry) // Size of Entry object * len of slice
    SizeInMem += A+B+C
}

fmt.Println("Size in Memory &v", SizeInMem)
```

Is this the correct way to determine the size of variable in memory?

Comment: Whether that's correct or not depends on what you're trying to measure. Are you trying to measure the size of the map and slices of entries only? Or do you want to measure the contained entries as well?

Comment: If the goal is to measure the size of all contained entries as well, there's probably no fool-proof way to do this. Each entry could be any size, from 0 bytes (an empty struct that satisfies the interface) to zettabytes (if you have some implementation that holds all of human knowledge in memory). And that's not even the complex part yet. What if you have the same instance in your list twice? Should that be counted once or twice? Worse: What if two instances share some part of their in-memory representation (like a database handle)? Should that be counted once or twice?

Comment: @Flimzy I am trying to calculate the size of variable in memory for only slices of entries.

Comment: So "complete variable" includes the actual `Entry` instances? Unfortunately, as eluded to above, there's no good way to do that.

Comment: No Only the slice of entries.. for each object of entry unsafe.sizeof(entry) gives 16 bytes but for the slice unsafe.sizeof(entries) gives 24 bytes. Lets say I have 5 elements in map, What size would the map take?

Comment: No, this is all wrong. Especially as your code does not include the internal map overhead and you simply _cannot_ know that. Whatever you try to do (XY problem?) redesign.

Comment: @Volker How can I correct my solution?

Comment: You simply cannot.

Comment: @ManishGupta: A Go map does not have a fixed size. It's dyamic. It depends on the implmentation.  It depends on the pattern of inserts, deletes, and updates.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a thing that you can calculate just in time...

But I prepared test playground for you.

https://play.golang.org/p/V_2fheWHQn-

```golang
type Entry interface {
    A() string
    B() string
    D() int64
}

type Entries []Entry
type EntryMap map[string]Entries

func main() {

    size := memcalc(func() {
        /* Put your code here */
        var hm = make(EntryMap)

        // do something with map, grow, for example        

        // pass variable to this function to measure
        calc(hm)
    })

    fmt.Println(size)
}
```